# Adjustments for multiple hypothesis testing ordered by conservativeness

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I am trying to get a grasp of the many different corrections methods there are out there to "correct" for multiple hypothesis testing. I know some differ with respect to the assumptions of the underlying data and tests, however I have also been reading that they differ in terms of their conservativeness, e.g. Bonferroni being quoted as more conservative than Benjamini-Hochberg. Does somebody know a good reference which classifies the methods according to their conservativeness?

Thanks!

Comment: Or to be more specific, does somebody know less conservative methods than BH correction?